# Encontrar texto en varios directorios

Tags: linux, grep

Tengo un directorio con un proyecto:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 dani staff  18K Mar  4 06:54 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 dani staff 1023 Mar 29 08:06 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 dani staff  129 Mar  2 15:33 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 dani staff  528 Mar 14 16:05 TODO
drwxr-xr-x 3 dani staff  102 Mar 29 08:09 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 dani staff  136 Mar 25 12:19 examples
drwxr-xr-x 5 dani staff  170 Mar  2 15:35 nbproject
drwxr-xr-x 4 dani staff  136 Mar  4 06:54 src
```

Necesito en el buscar una función `iniciarEjecucion`, he encontrado información acerca de un de comando que me pueden servir.

- grep

Entonces procedí a buscar el texto:

```
grep iniciarEjecucion *
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error:

```
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: examples: Is a directory
grep: nbproject: Is a directory
grep: src: Is a directory
```

Es necesario que ingrese a cada directorio para hacer la búsqueda de un texto con `grep`?

Es decir, mi pregunta es:

*Como puedo buscar un texto, en múltiples directorios?*

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si miras la [documentacion de grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) *(en Ingles)*, podrias encontrar los siguientes, parametros:

> -R, -r, --recursive
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

*Traduciendolo al Español:*

> -R, -r, --recursive
>
> Lee todos los archivos bajo cada directorio, de manera recursiva, es equivalente a la opcion -d.

**Que quiere decir esto?**

Que si quiere buscar un texto, en multiples directorios y los subdirectorios que en ellos se encuentran, solo bastaria que hicieras esto:

```
grep -R iniciarEjecucion *
```

En este caso `grep` buscara tu texto en `*`, el comodin `*` quiere decir, todos los archivos/directorios que se encuentren en el directorio donde estes en el momento.

#### Ademas

Puedes agregar distintos parametros en `grep`, supongamos que quieres **conocer el numero de la linea**, o bien, que quieres que **ignore mayusculas y minusculas**, bien podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
grep -R -i -n iniciarEjecucion *
```

De acuerdo a la documentacion de grep.

Para ignorar las mayusculas:

```
-i, --ignore-case
    Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files. (-i is specified by POSIX .)
```

*Traduciendolo al Español:*

```
-i, --ignore-case
        Ignora las apariciones de mayusculas o minusculas tanto en el patron (texto que buscas) como en los archivos de entrada. (Especificado por POSIX)
```

Para obtener el numero de la linea:

```
-n, --line-number
    Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file. (-n is specified by POSIX .)
```

*Traduciendolo al Español:*

```
-n, --line-number
    Agrega el prefijo a cada linea de salida con el numero donde se encuentra en el archivo buscado. (-n es especificado por POSIX .)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, no conocía los otros parámetros, los usare en mi requerimiento.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar -r para hacer una búsqueda recursiva

```
grep iniciarEjecucion * -r
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.